# Higher precision floating point calculations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, floating-point, shader, compute-shader

I would like to find a way to make higher precision calculations in a compute shader using multiple floats to represent a single number.

My goal is a mandelbrot renderer where you can zoom deeper than the usual float precision would allow. Performance isn't too crucial, since it will only be calculated once and stored in a texture.

I'm testing the algorithms in C#. So far I managed to add 2 numbers with sufficient accuracy:

```
double a = Math.PI * 10;
double b = Math.E * .1;
double c = a + b;

float ax = (float)a;
float ay = (float)(a - ax);
float bx = (float)b;
float by = (float)(b - bx);

float cx = ax + bx;
float cy = 0;

if (Math.Abs(ax) > Math.Abs(bx)) {
    cy = -cx + ax + bx + ay + by;
} else {
    cy = -cx + bx + ax + by + ay;
}

// cx + (double)cy = 
//     0 10000000011 1111101100000001000010110001011110001010110010100000 | 31.68775471874380
// c = 0 10000000011 1111101100000001000010110001011110001010110010101001 | 31.68775471874380
```

Extending this algorithm to 3 floats per number makes the sum exactly equal the double value.

Can you think of a way to multiply two of these numbers? And if you're having fun, division or inverting (to then multiply) a number maybe. The other calculations can be broken down into mul and add.

(I'm also open to other methods of getting a high zoom image of the mandelbrot set.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `double` is just a larger `float` bitwise.  They are both floating point.  Curious, why constrain this to just `float`?

Comment: @Zer0 I don't think compute shaders support the double type. Defining the number as a double was just for testing if the result matches.

Comment: Compute shaders do support double precision floating point, depending on the API and hardware.  That's why I asked.  [DirectX 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_feature) has support for this, for example.  Can you tag this question with the API you're using?

Comment: @Zer0 Oh I'm sorry then :) Yeah using doubles would be smarter then. Do you know if doubles are supported in Unity's shaders?

Comment: I primarily use DirectX, OpenGL and OpenCL.  Not an expert at unity.  Perhaps someone else can help answer if it does or how you can effectively get double precision.  Unity isn't a graphics API, it's an engine.

Comment: @Zer0 Thanks for your help so far, but my goal is to not to emulate a double, but to get arbitrary precision using some amount of floats (or doubles). I'm sorry if my question was misleading in this regard.

Comment: Not using `double` has an advantage.  It allows a `float-float` code as here to be tested against `double`.  If code written well, that could port to `double-double`.

Comment: Note: "if you're having fun, division or inverting a number maybe."  --> once mult and inverting done, division (the tricky one) is then a chain of those 2.

Comment: Maybe you could even use [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.decimal) `The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors. The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding.`